# Stringing together multiple page object files in Eclipse/Cucumber/Java

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber

I am having trouble stringing together multiple Page Object Files and step definitions.

I have imported the following, which is super heavily edited due to it being work code:

```
package <the package my step definition file is in>
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import <the other project my team created>.browsercapabilities.Browser;
import <the other project my team created>.Browsers;
import <a package a different step definition file is 
in>.addNewContact.AddNewContactStepDefs;

import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import <the other project my team created>.webcomponents.WebButton;
import <my page objects package>.authenticationpages.CommandLoginPage;
import <my page object package>ThirdPageObjectFile;
import <my page object package>.SecondPageObjectFile;
import <my page object package>.FirstPageObjectFile;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class ThirdPageStepDefs extends BrowserBase {

private static final Logger LOG = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThirdPageStepDefs.class);
private WebDriver driver = mainBrowser().getDriver();
private Browser browser = Browsers.getBrowser();
private WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

LoginPage login = new LoginPage (browser);
SecondPageObjectFile contact = new SecondPageObjectFile (browser);
FirstPageObjectFile searchContact = new FirstPageObjectFile (browser);
ThirdPageObjectFile deal = new ThirdPageObjectFile (browser);


@Then("^I click the contacts icon$")
public void i_click_the_contacts_icon() throws Throwable {
    contact.get_contact_link().clickLink();
}
```

I was getting an initialization error when I ran the runner code saying that the runner could not instantiate an instance of my ThirdStepDefFile, i.e. "Failed to Instantiate Class "

My runner is working fine:

```
package <Utility package>.utilities;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features="src\\test\\resources\\<my feature folder>", 
    plugin={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", 
"json:target/cucumber.json"},
    glue= "<My step def folder>",
    tags = "@<my tags>"
    )
public class ComUITestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

I have many more lines in scenarios that I've commented out and since I was getting the initialization error, I edited to troubleshoot as following:
-Comment all methods out (green)
-Leave all methods in (red)
-Leave one method in (red)

When I have even one method that isn't commented out, then I get an error.

My project is a series of screens that a user has to get to in order to log in. The login screen, first screen, second screen, and third screen all have their own page objects. Eventually I want to abstract those screens out to a main project that all sub projects share as they'll be pre-conditions to everything else. Stringing these screens together seems to fail and I'm considering refactoring the whole thing.

Am also new to Java/Eclipse, so it's possible that I am not seeing the stack trace correctly. For instance, the bottom of my junit screen says "62 more" lines detailing the failure that I'm not able to see. I tried debugging to no avail and I clicked on the outline on the left hand side of the junit output and when I hovered over it, it says Test Class Not Found

Comment: So after banging my head against a wall for four or five hours I figured that if I move the methods from one set of step defs to another set of step defs, everything magically worked even though both step def files reference the same set of page objects and I think all step defs can be run from anywhere anyway. Now I am still getting the same error but I am at least three or four methods ahead of where I was getting the error the first time.

Comment: Why are u using both junit and testng runner? Choose one. Can u add the stacktrace to the question